# AWS Lambda Layer: No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'"

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I have a library that I downloaded here:

[psycopg2](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/)

I tried all stakeoverflow suggestions thus far but they didn't work.

I placed it in a folder like this then zipped it to a python.zip folder on windows. The libraries inside are unzipped.

[image]

Then I created a lambda layer like this:

[image]

I've made sure that the runtime for layer and the function are the same, can someone please assist? Been struggling with this for more than a day.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Lambda uses the Amazon Linux environment, if you are using windows and create a zip file of dependencies it might not work while you run your lambda function. It will be better if you create the layer as a docker env. Please check below:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-python-packages-for-aws-lambda-layers/

Answer (score 1):

You need To compile it within a similar architecture as the lambda runtime. I would log into an Amazon Linux EC2 install psycopg there into a specific directory, then copy those files to your Lambda layer on your Windows machine.

Can send more specific steps if you need.